# TKinter Modify an Entry during a for

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to modify an Entry from TKinter in a for loop.
But the windows doesn't not have to time to open itself. I tried to add a sleep command, but it didn't work neither.
It seems possible since I've added a print of the variable and this one displays correctly.
The rest of the code works fine, my only issue is this point
(I use an Toplevel here because I'm already in a Tk window)

```
     def training(self, epochs, target_list, input_list):
        L=[i for i in range(100)]
        N=len(target_list)
        compteur=0
        pourcentage=0
        prog = Tk()
        prog.title("Avancement entraînement")
        prog.iconbitmap("icone.ico")
        prog.config(bg=couleur)
        prog.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: prog.destroy())
        prog.minsize(700, 150)
        prog.focus_force()
        var = StringVar()
        var.set("696")
        pourcent = Label(prog, font=('Helvetica', 15), textvariable=var, bg=couleur)
        pourcent.pack()
        for i in range(epochs):
            for j in range(len(target_list)):
                compteur+=100/(N*epochs)
                if compteur>pourcentage:
                    pourcentage+=1
                    print(pourcentage)
                    var.set(str(pourcentage))
                self.backpropagation(input_list[j],target_list[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retry your test with the `after` method instead of `time.sleep` because the `sleep` function will *freeze* the window.

You can use the `after` method like this:

```py
from tkinter import*
window = Tk()
window.after(1000, lambda: Label(window, text="Print after 1 second").pack())
window.mainloop()
```